# Execute function multiple times without using a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table with IDs:

```
ObjectId
----------
100
101
102
```

I'd would like to execute a function fn_GetStuff(Id) multiple times like this:

```
fn_GetStuff(100)
fn_GetStuff(101)
fn_GetStuff(102)
```

Is it possible to do this without using a loop?

I tried this it doesn't work:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
INNER JOIN fn_GetStuff(myTable.ObjectId)
```

Comment: You need to put the schema in front of the function. This is a requirement. There are two types of answers below, one is for scalar functions and the other is for in-line table valued functions. One of them is right, but make sure to append the schema in all cases.

Comment: Is this a table-valued function?

Comment: Yes its a table-valued function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OP is using a in-line table valued function it looks like so they would need a `CROSS APPLY`...

```
Select  *
From    myTable mt
Cross   Apply schema.fn_GetStuff(mt.ObjectID) f
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your function is a scalar-valued function, you can just do:

```
select fn_GetStuff(Objectid)
from myTable
```

If your function is table valued, then you would need to use `cross apply`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to join because there isn't another table. You should be okay to do this:

```
SELECT fn_GetSTuff(t.ObjectId)
FROM myTable t
```